# How to use regular expression when there are 2 dynamic values in the same URL and 1 of which changes continuously?

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract 2 dynamic values from the URL -

1. id

- I used the regular expression (.+?) and added to path - /blazor?${id}
- I see invalid character error in View results tree.

2. the number after &_ which changes for each request.

- Is it possible to extract a value which changes continuously? How can it be implemented?

Sample URL's:

```
https://abc.abc.com:8443/_blazor?id=jTl2weD7HcQIS78PcBHbVg&_=1606828427324

https://abc.abc.com:8443/_blazor?id=jTl2weD7HcQIS78PcBHbVg

https://abc.abc.com:8443/_blazor?id=jTl2weD7HcQIS78PcBHbVg&_=1606828427575

https://abc.abc.com:8443/_blazor?id=jTl2weD7HcQIS78PcBHbVg&_=1606828427756

https://abc.abc.com:8443/_blazor?id=jTl2weD7HcQIS78PcBHbVg&_=1606828427885
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This number is utterly like to be a current [timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) so instead of extracting you can use JMeter's [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) for generating it:

   [image]
2. If you use just `(.+?)` - it will match the first character in the URL (which is `h`) and then stop, if you want to get the ID the relevant regular expression should be something like:

   ```
    id=(.+?)&
   ```

   [image]

   similarly for the timestamp (or whatever it is)

   _=(\d+)

   [image]

   or if you want everything after `blazor?`

   _blazor?(.*)

   [image]

If you're not too comfortable with regular expressions you may find [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) easier to use, all you need to do is to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and it will capture everything "in between":

[image]

as a little bonus - it works much faster and consumes less resources. More information - [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)